# Electron-react-broilerplate how to switch out flow for typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have tried to read tutorials on how to use typescript for electron and react, but they don't explain it in the context of electron-react-boilerplate because the files and codes are structured differently plus they don't show how to replace electron/react/flow with typescript--- only explains adding typescript to electron/react.

I followed this guide: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

The order is use typescript -> babel -> webpack > bundle.js right?
Which entry point should typescript use to start transpiling? And what should I use for output (tsx-to-js) file to?